# Showing that $\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ for $n \geq 2$ is not an integer .

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Suppose $n\geq2 ,s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}} $ 
$$s(2)=1+\frac 12=1.5\\s(3)=1+\frac12+\frac14=1.75 ,\\\vdots$$
Is an elementary proof to $s(n)$ can never be an integer number ?

As honestly as possible : One of my students( k-12) asked this question .I said I will think and answer .But I got stuck ...
I am thankful for your hint,guide or solutions in advanced.

Comment: $K-12$ is an awfully large range. On the very upper end, one can show using induction that $s(n) = 2 - 2^{1 - s}$, and so $1 < s(n) < 2$ for $n \geq 2$.  But probably a "proof by picture" would anyway be most illuminating.

Comment: How far would you have to go in the sequence to get to $2$?

Comment: $2^{n-1} s(n)$ is odd, hence $s(n)$ cannot be an integer.

Comment: Use [Zeno's argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox) to show that $s(n)$ cannot reach 2...

Comment: @leonbloy : DO you mean to show $1<s(n)<2$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2^{n-1} s(n)$ is odd and $\frac{\text{odd}}{\text{even}\neq 0}$ cannot be an integer.

Comment: :Thank you all . now I have a temptation to find more Idea(s) !

Comment: :Is this prove suitable  for $n\geq2 ,s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{3^{k-1}}$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash: with a small adjustment, sure. The ratio between a positive integer of the form $3k+1$ and a positive integer of the form $3m$ is never an integer.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose it were an integer, say $K$.

Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} = K$$

Multiply by $2^n$ on both sides.
Then LHS is $1+2+2^2+...$ which is odd, but RHS is even. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute as sum of geometric progression $\sum_{i={1}}^n \frac{1}{2^{i-1}} = \frac{1 - (1/2)^{n}}{1 - 1/2} = 2 - (1/2)^{n-1} $

Comment: Where can I go with sum of geometric progression ? how can I show  ?

Comment: $s(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n aq^{i-1} = a\frac{1 - q^n}{1-q}$ - is a formula of g.p. sum. In your case you have $a = q = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: you can read it on wiki for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: I know this formula .my question is: how can I use this to show $s(n)$ never be an integer ?

Comment: $s(2)>1$ and $s(n)<2$ for all $n$. How many integers are there strictly between $1$ and $2$ ?

Comment: $s(n) = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \in (0, 1)$ since some n. it's obvious

Comment: only limit $\sum_1^\infty q^{i-1} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

We can convert all of the fractions in the expansion to the same base, and then add them up. We then get the result $\frac{2^k}{2^k-1}$. Since the denominator is greater than the numerator, it does not divide the numerator, showing that it is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sum_{k=1}^1 \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ is $1$, showing that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ is not an integer is equivalent to show that $\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ is not an integer.

$$\begin{align}1&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\\ 
&=\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\\
&=S_1+S_2\\
\end{align}$$

Since $1$, the minimum positive integer, cannot be obtained as the sum of two positive integers and both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are positive, neither $S_1$ nor $S_2$ are integers.